# systemctl nginx doesn't start

Tags: 20.04, nginx

After updating one of the index files in website directory when I run `systemctl start nginx` it tells that there was an error and `journalctl -xe` shows:

```
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "example.com" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/analytics.conf:12.
```

I didn't change anything about this file and when I check the site with port it works perfectly in browser, but even when I reversed index file of other website it still doesn't change at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/analytics.conf:12.
```

The error says, on line 12 .
You should search for "example.com" and replace it with your domain address.

Another thing, nginx , the configuration is checked if it is correct with nginx -t, and if everything is ok, the service is restarted